# How to get part of the path with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have following URL `www.webiste.com/Services/allservices.html`

How could I get part of this URL with jQuery?

e.g '`services'`
or '`allservices.html'`

Any suggestion much appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var url = "www.webiste.com/Services/allservices.html"
    url = url.split("/");
    alert(url[1]);
```

In the above example split the string `url` when find `/` (separator) and save it in an array. Then using the proper index, you can use the substring you wish (in the above example will alert `Services`).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jcNSs/

More info for `split()` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 7):

```
var url = 'http://www.website.com/Services/allservices.html';

// Getting the file name (allservices.html)
var fn = url.split('/').reverse()[0];

// Getting the extension (html)
var ext = url.split('/').reverse()[0].split('.').reverse()[0];

// Getting the last middle part (services)
var lm = url.split('/').reverse()[1];
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the JavaScript `window.location` you can split `location.pathname` using '/' and use `pop()` to get the last element or get by index:

```
var splitUrlArray = urlString.split('/'); 
var lastPart = splitUrlArray.pop();
var firstPart = splitUrlArray[0];
```

Read http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-window-location for more details on the `window.location`.

Answer (score 2):

Split it by "/" and then choose the last element.

```
var parts = $("selectorForText").val().split("/");
//parts[0] = www.website.com
//parts[1] = Services
//parts[2] = allservices.html
```

Something to that effect will work - the important bits being the `split()` function and the recognition that it returns an array of strings

--Edited to provide example--

Comment: An ex would be useful to the OP i think

Comment: No real reason, it's just an example of splitting a string. In this instance, the example is pulling it out of a textbox (or so I hope, my jQuery is a tad rusty!)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a jQuery problem as there are a couple of javascript functions that can help you (obviously it'll still work in and around jQuery). The easiest way is to just split on the path separator and then manipulate it however you like:

```
a = "www.website.com/Services/allservices.html".split("/")

 => ["www.website.com", "Services", "allservices.html"]
```

Then you can piece it together however you like:

- Host

  a.slice(0) => "www.website.com"
- Path

  a.slice(1, a.size()) => ["Services", "allservices.html"]
  a.slice(1, a.size()).join("/") => "Services/allservices.html"

etc.

Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another simpler way:

```
urlParts = "www.website.com/About/subpage1.html".split("/")
    var Part1= urlParts[1]+"/";   // e.g. About/
    var Part2 = urlParts[2];      // e.g. subpage1.html
```