# Get Attribute from URL in ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have url like below

http://ixorra.com/products/27/13

I want 27 value in view

My URL Routing config like :

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "IxorraExports.Controllers" }
        );
```

Any idea how to get a value of 27 in view.

Comment: According to your route, `27` is the name of your action method.  Is it?  It's not clear to me what you mean by "get it in the view" or what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get part of the path with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609996/how-to-get-part-of-the-path-with-jquery)

Comment: In URL  "Products" is Action method name and 27 is my first parameter of action method and 13 is the second parameter of action method

Comment: in that case you're missing controller name

Comment: Controller name is home and "Home" is default controller in Route configuration

Comment: That's not how Url routing works. If I understood correctly you're doing `website/action/param1/param2` and your url mapping says `{controller}/{action}/{id}`. In that case defaults don't apply. It's going to look for a controller called "products", action "27" and pass Id="13"

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments on the question above:

> In URL "Products" is Action method name and 27 is my first parameter of action method and 13 is the second parameter of action method.
>   Controller name is home and "Home" is default controller in Route configuration.

First of all, your URL is wrong.  You forgot the controller.  It should be:

```
http://ixorra.com/home/products/27/13
```

Once you've corrected that, you'll just need to add another optional parameter to your route configuration.  This would only change these lines:

```
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{foo}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, foo = UrlParameter.Optional },
```

Naturally, you'll want to use a more meaningful name than `foo`.  But we don't know what these values mean, so that's just a placeholder for now.

Your controller action can then accept those URL parameters:

```
public ActionResult Products(int id, int foo)
{
    // your action method
}
```

(This is where the more meaningful name becomes, well, meaningful.  Whatever common generic name would make sense for that second parameter is what you'd use both in the route definition and in the method definition.)

At this point you have the value, so you can do whatever you like with it.  Add it to the model that gets sent to the view, send it in the `ViewBag`, etc.  For example:

```
public ActionResult Products(int id, int foo)
{
    ViewBag.foo = foo;
    return View();
}
```

Then in your view you can access the value from the `ViewBag`:

```
<span>The value is: @ViewBag.foo</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by split the url:

```
var url = $(location).attr('href');
var parts = url.split("/");
alert(parts[0]);
```

you can desired part usinf proper index.
I hope it can help!

Comment: i want this value in HTML not in script portion LIKE Below

@section meta_tags
{
  if(value which are we are want)
{

}

Comment: I think HTML is a markup language, not a programming language. You'll need to use either JavaScript or some server side language to access and process the query string

Comment: or you can get the part you need in code behind and then pass it to view with viewmodel or viewbag or some thing like this.